# Define a show method for an S3 class

Tags: r, show, r-s4

I'm quite stunned to find out that show is an S4 generic, and that I can't find a way to use the S3 dispatching to get a show function to work. A simple demonstration:

```
> x <- 1:5
> xx <- structure(x,class="aClass")

> show.aClass <- function(object){
+     cat("S3 dispatching.\n")
+     print(object)
+ }

> xx
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

No S3 dispatching here...

```
> setMethod("show","aClass",function(object){
+     cat("S4 dispatching.\n")
+     print(object)
+ })
in method for ‘show’ with signature ‘"aClass"’: no definition for class “aClass”
[1] "show"

> xx
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

What did you think?

```
> print.aClass <- function(object){
+     cat("the print way...\n")
+     print(as.vector(object)) #drop class to avoid infinite loop!
+ }

> xx
the print way...
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

And for print it works.

I have pretty good reasons to stay with S3 (of which a big part is the minimization of overhead, as the objects will be used extensively in bootstrapping). How am I supposed to define a different show and print method here?

Comment: This is trivial to do when you just want to define a `show` method for S3, but I haven't been able to find a way of doing that and not destroy the S4 show method.

Comment: @Andrie : It's a tricky one, isn't it?

Comment: Show is just the S4 equivalent of print. Not sure why you'd want different results from each.

Comment: @hadley There used to be a show() in S3 as well, where show defaulted to print, but could be defined to have a different result. This would allow you to get a basic output when typing the object name at the prompt, but a more nicely formatted output when using print(). I understood from my colleague that this would be unexpected behaviour, so I just left it at that.

Comment: Are you sure?  I've never been aware of show having an S3 version.  It would certainly be unexpected if `(x)` and `print(x)`  display different things.

Comment: @hadley: not sure, and apparently I misunderstood some documentation. I've been going through my old R installations, and even in 2.6.1 it's an S4. Thx for the correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe

```
setOldClass("aClass")
setMethod(show, "aClass", function(object) cat("S4\n"))
print.aClass <- function(object) { cat("S3... "); show(object) }
```

and then

```
> structure(1:5, class="aClass")
S3... S4
```

But I'm not really understanding what you want to do.

Comment: setOldClass... How did I forget about that one? I'm trying to get a quick overview of the object when I just type the name at the console, but a bit nicer outprint when I use the print() function. In the meantime I forgot about trying that as a colleague rightly pointed out that would hardly be expected behaviour. Thx anyway for the answer.